# How to change an attribute's parent object. (as such that self.myobject.myattribute becomes self.myattribute)

Tags: python, class, attributes, relationship

first of all my apologies in case I have or will mix up terms like object, class, attribute, parent, child. This question does not relate to class inheritance.

Within my main class (hereby called parent) I call a function that returns an object (hereby called child) and assigns it to parent as an attribute. This child can now be referenced as usual via parent.child and the child attributes via parent.child.attribute.

My goal now is to find a way to access all of the child's attributes as attributes of parent. In essence, to elevate all of these attributes one level up.

Intuitively one solution would be to iterate over all of the child's attributes via `child.__dict__` (or such) and then dynamically create attributes within the parent that have the same name as the retrieved attributes. 
However this seems quite inefficient and I read that dynamic creation of variables is to be avoided when possible.

Originally

```py
def stub_that_returns_object():
    return Child()

class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = stub_that_returns_object()

class Child():
    def __init__(self):
        self.somestr= "foo"
        self.someint = 42
        self.someobj = object()

p = Parent()
print(p.child.somestr)
```

what i want now is some smart way to call then unchangeable(!) stub_that_returns_object" function but instead of using the child object i want to be able to access the attributes like

```py
p = Parent()
print(p.somestr)
```

...and so on

I hope i have made myself somewhat understood. The child object may be deleted in the process of elevating all its attributes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand correctly, you wish access the child attribue from the parent class.

You can do it by having a method in the parent class that return the attribute of the child :

```
class Parent():
   def __init__(self):
        self.child = stub_that_returns_object()

   def getSomestr():
        return self.child.somestr

class Child():
    def __init__(self):
        self.somestr= "foo"
        self.someint = 42
        self.someobj = object()

p = Parent()
print(p.getSomestr())
```

And the other hand, if you want the parent to have the attribute of the child, you can also assign the same attribute for the parent class since

Comment: Thanks. Accessing is not the crucial point for me. In the end it is paramount that the attributes are actually attached to the parent class.

Comment: Ok, then does your Child class inherited from your Parent Class ? For the example you provide, the Parent class have as a attribue a Child class. With mean that your Child class does not have any relation with you Parent Class

Comment: In my actual case, the parent object's class is a subclass of the child object's class. So yes: Right now the child object is just an attribute of the parent object.